switch statement "returning" a View?
In a view I have a switch statement, where each case is a view, along these lines:
Color.clear
  .overlay {
    switch x {
    case let .text(text):
      vis.textToImage()
        .resizable().scaledToFill().tag(vis)
    case .image:
      vis.imageAsImageView()
        .resizable().scaledToFill().tag(vis)
    default:
      Image(systemName: "x.circle")
        .resizable().scaledToFill().tag(vis)
    }
  }

So I want to move the ".resizable().scaledToFill().tag(vis)" to the switch statement, like this:
Color.clear
  .overlay {
    switch x {
    case .text:
      vis.textToImage()
    case .image:
      vis.imageAsImageView()
    default:
      Image(systemName: "x.circle")
    }
    .resizable().scaledToFill().tag(vis)
  }

But then I get a compiler error: Type '() -> ()' cannot conform to 'ShapeStyle'.
What is it that I'm doing wrong? Doesn't the switch statement "return" whatever the "case" is? It appears to be that simple in the first code example (which is working)?

Normally, when you want to add view modifiers to all the views that can be generated by an if/switch, you would surround the if/switch with a Group.
Group {
    if someCondition {
        View1()
    } else {
        View2()
    }
}
// these modifiers will be applied to View1 if someCondition is true, and View2 otherwise
.fooModifier()
.barModifier()

However, resizable is only available on Image, so this doesn't work here.
Because resizable is only available on Image, this means that every branch of the switch produces an Image (otherwise it wouldn't make sense), so you can just assign the whole switch to a local let, and add modifiers onto that.
.overlay {
    let image = switch x {
    case .text:
        vis.textToImage()
    case .image:
        vis.imageAsImageView()
    default:
        Image(systemName: "x.circle")
    }
    image.resizable().scaledToFill().tag(vis)
}


Regarding

What is it that I'm doing wrong? Doesn't the switch statement "return" whatever the "case" is? It appears to be that simple in the first code example (which is working)?

While yes, switch is an expression thanks to SE-380, but it can only be used as an expression in very specific contexts - after return, and as the right hand side of an assignment (like in  let image = above)
You are using it as the receiver of the .resizable().scaledToFill().tag(vis) chain, which is neither of those. Even if switch can be used like this, you would still need to add () around the switch for the parser to parse this correctly.
In the first code example, switch works because of @ViewBuilder. You are not using switch as an expression.

In its original form, the switch statement performs as a ViewBuilder.
It you just required the switch to return a View then you could wrap the re-factored switch statement as a Group and it would work. This would give you a nested ViewBuilder.
However, the modifier .resizable() doesn't work on a View. So the switch needs to return an Image instead.
What you can do is move the switch to a computed property that returns an Image. Something like:
private var imageForX: Image {
    switch x {
    case .text:
        vis.textToImage()
    case .image:
        vis.imageAsImageView()
    default:
        Image(systemName: "x.circle")
    }
}

Color.clear
    .overlay {
        imageForX
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .tag(vis)
    }

